# Argument order with python functools partial

Tags: python, multiprocessing, functools

I am trying to using multiprocessing with `pool.map` to speed execution of a function, but the iterable is not the first argument for that function.  Lambdas won't work because they aren't pickleable.  I tried to use `functools.partial` to create a new function, but it fails with a `TypeError`.  Below is a very simple example with the same result.  If I switch the argument order to `f(i, s1, s2)`, it works as expected.

Why does the argument order matter here?  It is not obvious to me when I read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

What are my options (other than the obvious of changing the original function)?

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial


def f(s1, s2, i):
    return [s1] + [s2]*i

def main():
    # other code... constants for f aren't known until runtime
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    func = partial(f, s1='a', s2='c')
    for strings in pool.map(func, range(10)):
        print(strings)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Update:
The best I can think of is to create a wrapper at the module level to switch argument order, then a partial from the wrapper.  Doesn't look pretty or seem pythonic at all.

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial


def f(s1, s2, i):
    return [s1] + [s2]*i

def wrapper(i, s1, s2):
    return f(s1, s2, i)

def main():
    # other code... constants for f aren't known until runtime
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    func = partial(wrapper, s1='foo', s2='bar')
    for strings in pool.map(func, range(10)):
        print(strings)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The order matters because `pool.map` is invoking `f(i, s1='a', s2='c')`.
You could write your partial like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(s1, s2, i):
    return [s1] + [s2]*i

def f2(i):
    return f('a','c',i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for strings in pool.map(f2, range(10)):
        print(strings)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If you are using python3.3, `pool.starmap` is available to you:

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import repeat

def f(s1, s2, i):
    return [s1] + [s2]*i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for strings in pool.starmap(f, zip(repeat('a'), repeat('c'), range(10))):
        print(strings)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: I can't just hard code the arguments with something like f2.  Those values aren't known until runtime.  I'll edit my question to make that clearer.  Also I still don't understand why argument order results in this error.  Thanks

Comment: @user2133814, sorry i meant invoking `f(i, s1='a', s2='c')` instead of `func(i, s1='a', s2='b')`. In other words, `partial` returns a callable object with 3 arguments and 2 of them now have default values.